# Awk command for powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, awk

Is there any command like `awk` in powershell?

I want to execute this command:

```
awk '
BEGIN {count=1}
/^Text/{text=$0}
/^Time/{time=$0}
/^Rerayzs/{retext=$0}
{
  if (NR % 3 == 0) {
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", text, time, retext) > (count ".txt")
    count++
  }
}' file
```

to a powershell command.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Cygwin with Powershell?  If not can you clarify that?

Comment: I am not familiar with Awk, but if you can state your originating text (or depersonalized sample), and desired output we can probably at least help you with some suggestions. I have a feeling that a RegEx match would probably do what you want.

Comment: your question is a little confusing. `awk` and `powershell` are both programming languages. Given the little I have read about `powershell`, I think you'll find that awk features of text processing are a sub-set of all of the features that powershell contains, with the warning that the extra features are designed to work in a very MSWindows-centric environment. . Good luck.

Comment: awk is a command which i use in bash programming and i want the same in powershell

Comment: I understand that, but Awk does not exist directly in PowerShell. There are probably other ways to accomplish what you want, but we need to know what you want more plainly than just the Awk command.

Comment: else you might want to rephrase this as "I must be able to call an awk program from inside powershell" (if that is what you want). That is different, and may not be very easy. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we like to see what you have tried. It at least shows that you are making an effort, and we aren't just doing your work for you. I think you're new to PowerShell, so I'm going to just spoon-feed you an answer, hoping that you use it to learn and expand your knowledge, and hopefully have better questions in the future.

I am pretty sure that this will accomplish the same thing as what you laid out. You have to give it an array of input (the contents of a text file, an array of strings, something like that), and it will generate several files depending on how many matches it finds for the treo "Text", "Time", and "Rerayzs". It will order them as Text, then a new line with Time, and then a new line with Rerayzs.

```
$Text,$Time,$Retext = $Null
$FileCounter = 1
gc c:\temp\test.txt|%{
    Switch($_){
        {$_ -match "^Text"} {$Text = $_}
        {$_ -match "^Time"} {$Time = $_}
        {$_ -match "^Rerayzs"} {$Retext = $_}
    }
    If($Text -and $Time -and $Retext){
        ("{0}`n{1}`n{2}") -f $Text,$Time,$Retext > "c:\temp\$FileCounter.txt"
        $FileCounter++
        $Text,$Time,$Retext = $Null
    }
}
```

That will get the text of a file `C:\Temp\Test.txt` and will output numbered files to the same location. The file I tested against is:

```
Text is good.
Rerayzs initiated.
Stuff to not include
Time is 18:36:12
Time is 20:21:22
Text is completed.
Rerayzs failed.
```

I was left with 2 files as output. The first reads:

```
Text is good.
Time is 18:36:12
Rerayzs initiated.
```

The second reads:

```
Text is completed.
Time is 20:21:22
Rerayzs failed.
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. Basically worked after some changes. I realy tried to do it in a lot of ways but i didn't make it. I had many errors and because i am new in powershell i didn't know what to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear that helped, please mark the answer as accepted if you're all set at this point so others can use your question as reference in the future.